# How to simulate text selection behavior on SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following svg element, and I'd like to allow the user to select paths on mouse click and drag just as if they're interacting with a normal text.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 238.9 39.28" height="75" width="190">

<rect class="opacity-0" x="231.47" width="15.74" height="26"/>
   
   <path d="M119.42,162.67h3.91v27.05h13V193H119.42Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M159.6,181.93c0,8.06-5.58,11.57-10.84,11.57-5.9,0-10.44-4.32-10.44-11.21,0-7.29,4.77-11.56,10.8-11.56C155.37,170.73,159.6,175.27,159.6,181.93Zm-17.28.23c0,4.77,2.75,8.36,6.62,8.36s6.61-3.55,6.61-8.45c0-3.69-1.84-8.37-6.52-8.37S142.32,178,142.32,182.16Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M164.6,178c0-2.57,0-4.77-.18-6.8h3.46l.14,4.28h.18a6.52,6.52,0,0,1,6-4.77,4.25,4.25,0,0,1,1.12.13v3.74a5.9,5.9,0,0,0-1.35-.14c-2.79,0-4.77,2.12-5.31,5.09a11.14,11.14,0,0,0-.18,1.84V193H164.6Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M181.07,182.83c.09,5.36,3.51,7.56,7.47,7.56a14.37,14.37,0,0,0,6-1.12l.67,2.83a17.61,17.61,0,0,1-7.24,1.35c-6.71,0-10.71-4.41-10.71-11s3.87-11.74,10.21-11.74c7.11,0,9,6.25,9,10.26a16,16,0,0,1-.13,1.84ZM192.68,180c0-2.52-1-6.44-5.49-6.44-4,0-5.76,3.69-6.08,6.44Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M201.41,177.12c0-2.25,0-4.1-.18-5.9h3.46l.18,3.51H205a7.5,7.5,0,0,1,6.84-4,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,6.16,4.36h.09a9,9,0,0,1,2.43-2.83,7.46,7.46,0,0,1,4.82-1.53c2.88,0,7.15,1.89,7.15,9.45V193h-3.87V180.67c0-4.18-1.53-6.7-4.72-6.7a5.12,5.12,0,0,0-4.68,3.6,6.52,6.52,0,0,0-.32,2V193H215V180c0-3.46-1.53-6-4.54-6a5.41,5.41,0,0,0-4.91,4,5.54,5.54,0,0,0-.31,1.93V193h-3.87Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M252.89,165.1a2.46,2.46,0,0,1-4.91,0,2.42,2.42,0,0,1,2.48-2.47A2.35,2.35,0,0,1,252.89,165.1ZM248.48,193V171.22h4V193Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M259,178.33c0-2.79-.09-5-.18-7.11h3.55l.18,3.74h.09a8.56,8.56,0,0,1,7.74-4.23c5.27,0,9.23,4.45,9.23,11.07,0,7.82-4.77,11.7-9.9,11.7a7.67,7.67,0,0,1-6.71-3.42h-.09v11.83H259Zm3.91,5.81a9,9,0,0,0,.18,1.62,6.12,6.12,0,0,0,5.94,4.63c4.19,0,6.62-3.42,6.62-8.41,0-4.37-2.3-8.1-6.48-8.1a6.32,6.32,0,0,0-6,4.9,6.69,6.69,0,0,0-.27,1.62Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M284.07,189a10.33,10.33,0,0,0,5.22,1.57c2.88,0,4.23-1.44,4.23-3.23s-1.12-2.93-4-4c-3.91-1.39-5.76-3.55-5.76-6.16,0-3.51,2.84-6.39,7.52-6.39a10.85,10.85,0,0,1,5.35,1.35l-1,2.88a8.46,8.46,0,0,0-4.45-1.26c-2.34,0-3.65,1.35-3.65,3,0,1.8,1.31,2.61,4.14,3.69,3.78,1.44,5.72,3.33,5.72,6.57,0,3.82-3,6.52-8.15,6.52a12.33,12.33,0,0,1-6.12-1.49Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M320.66,187.06c0,2.25,0,4.23.18,5.94h-3.51l-.23-3.55H317a8.2,8.2,0,0,1-7.2,4.05c-3.42,0-7.51-1.9-7.51-9.54V171.22h4v12.06c0,4.14,1.26,6.93,4.86,6.93a5.72,5.72,0,0,0,5.22-3.6,5.86,5.86,0,0,0,.36-2V171.22h4Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
    <path d="M327.23,177.12c0-2.25-.05-4.1-.18-5.9h3.46l.18,3.51h.14a7.5,7.5,0,0,1,6.84-4,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,6.16,4.36h.09a9,9,0,0,1,2.43-2.83,7.46,7.46,0,0,1,4.82-1.53c2.88,0,7.15,1.89,7.15,9.45V193h-3.87V180.67c0-4.18-1.53-6.7-4.72-6.7a5.12,5.12,0,0,0-4.68,3.6,6.52,6.52,0,0,0-.32,2V193h-3.87V180c0-3.46-1.53-6-4.54-6a5.41,5.41,0,0,0-4.91,4,5.54,5.54,0,0,0-.31,1.93V193h-3.87Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)"/>
</svg>
```

In the following image, the first line is real text I'm selecting part of it, the second line is the rendering of the svg code above.

[image]

I've tried few JavaScripts approaches after reading [W3 SVG 1.1 / 16 Interactivity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html), but I was only able to change classes and few attributes of the svg element.

---

### Update

The behavior I'm looking for is simple, once the use clicks and drags the mouse of the svg, I need to show a background of some kind. To achieve this goal, I modified my svg to a add a hidden rectangle that gets displayed once on `mousedown` event:

```html
<rect class="opacity-0" x="231.47" width="15.74" height="26"/>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  var verse = document.getElementById('2-6');
  verse.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let elements = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].localName === 'rect') {
        elements[i].style.opacity = "0.5"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I'm almost there, but not yet.

Comment: How exactly should it be interacting?
Should the user be able to select and copy text?
Or just mark the text? Only select on letter basis, or select any space of the svg?

Comment: create hidden text on top of the paths and let the user select the hidden text.

Comment: @Lalalena I added an update with one of my trials. Basically, the behavior I'm looking for is once the use clicks and drags the mouse on the svg, I need to show a background of some kind. To achieve this goal, I modified my svg to a add a hidden rectangle that gets displayed once on mousedown event:

Comment: @RobertLongson you can't really do that because the selection (blue) background is going to be hidden two. Plus, the whole reason I'm doing this is because the typeface is so complicated it doesn't have a ttf version of it.

Comment: @iamjazzar have you ever viewed a PDF in Firefox's built in viewer? That's how it works and it's pretty successful. You only need to get pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with `<canvas>`, `<rect>` and javascript, I've decided to give Robert's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866594/how-to-simulate-text-selection-behavior-on-svg#comment126997704_71866594) another try which amazingly worked.

The idea is to:

- Create a companion div to the svg.
- Position the `svg` on top of it.
- Give that companion div the closest attributes to the original font (i.e. `font-size`, `text-align`, `line-height`, and `font-family`) so that when someone copies the text, you get some accuracy there.
- Make the companion div text color `transparent` (Opacity won't work) to show the selection background but not the selected text.
- Finally, the SVG needs its `position` to be `absolute` and `pointer-events` to be `none`.

Few weeks here and there might be needed, but just wanted to share the path that I'm going with in case you face the same problem.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.companion {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 4.2rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
  
svg {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 238.9 39.28" height="75" width=190>
      <path d="M119.42,162.67h3.91v27.05h13V193H119.42Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M159.6,181.93c0,8.06-5.58,11.57-10.84,11.57-5.9,0-10.44-4.32-10.44-11.21,0-7.29,4.77-11.56,10.8-11.56C155.37,170.73,159.6,175.27,159.6,181.93Zm-17.28.23c0,4.77,2.75,8.36,6.62,8.36s6.61-3.55,6.61-8.45c0-3.69-1.84-8.37-6.52-8.37S142.32,178,142.32,182.16Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M164.6,178c0-2.57,0-4.77-.18-6.8h3.46l.14,4.28h.18a6.52,6.52,0,0,1,6-4.77,4.25,4.25,0,0,1,1.12.13v3.74a5.9,5.9,0,0,0-1.35-.14c-2.79,0-4.77,2.12-5.31,5.09a11.14,11.14,0,0,0-.18,1.84V193H164.6Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M181.07,182.83c.09,5.36,3.51,7.56,7.47,7.56a14.37,14.37,0,0,0,6-1.12l.67,2.83a17.61,17.61,0,0,1-7.24,1.35c-6.71,0-10.71-4.41-10.71-11s3.87-11.74,10.21-11.74c7.11,0,9,6.25,9,10.26a16,16,0,0,1-.13,1.84ZM192.68,180c0-2.52-1-6.44-5.49-6.44-4,0-5.76,3.69-6.08,6.44Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M201.41,177.12c0-2.25,0-4.1-.18-5.9h3.46l.18,3.51H205a7.5,7.5,0,0,1,6.84-4,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,6.16,4.36h.09a9,9,0,0,1,2.43-2.83,7.46,7.46,0,0,1,4.82-1.53c2.88,0,7.15,1.89,7.15,9.45V193h-3.87V180.67c0-4.18-1.53-6.7-4.72-6.7a5.12,5.12,0,0,0-4.68,3.6,6.52,6.52,0,0,0-.32,2V193H215V180c0-3.46-1.53-6-4.54-6a5.41,5.41,0,0,0-4.91,4,5.54,5.54,0,0,0-.31,1.93V193h-3.87Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M252.89,165.1a2.46,2.46,0,0,1-4.91,0,2.42,2.42,0,0,1,2.48-2.47A2.35,2.35,0,0,1,252.89,165.1ZM248.48,193V171.22h4V193Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M259,178.33c0-2.79-.09-5-.18-7.11h3.55l.18,3.74h.09a8.56,8.56,0,0,1,7.74-4.23c5.27,0,9.23,4.45,9.23,11.07,0,7.82-4.77,11.7-9.9,11.7a7.67,7.67,0,0,1-6.71-3.42h-.09v11.83H259Zm3.91,5.81a9,9,0,0,0,.18,1.62,6.12,6.12,0,0,0,5.94,4.63c4.19,0,6.62-3.42,6.62-8.41,0-4.37-2.3-8.1-6.48-8.1a6.32,6.32,0,0,0-6,4.9,6.69,6.69,0,0,0-.27,1.62Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M284.07,189a10.33,10.33,0,0,0,5.22,1.57c2.88,0,4.23-1.44,4.23-3.23s-1.12-2.93-4-4c-3.91-1.39-5.76-3.55-5.76-6.16,0-3.51,2.84-6.39,7.52-6.39a10.85,10.85,0,0,1,5.35,1.35l-1,2.88a8.46,8.46,0,0,0-4.45-1.26c-2.34,0-3.65,1.35-3.65,3,0,1.8,1.31,2.61,4.14,3.69,3.78,1.44,5.72,3.33,5.72,6.57,0,3.82-3,6.52-8.15,6.52a12.33,12.33,0,0,1-6.12-1.49Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M320.66,187.06c0,2.25,0,4.23.18,5.94h-3.51l-.23-3.55H317a8.2,8.2,0,0,1-7.2,4.05c-3.42,0-7.51-1.9-7.51-9.54V171.22h4v12.06c0,4.14,1.26,6.93,4.86,6.93a5.72,5.72,0,0,0,5.22-3.6,5.86,5.86,0,0,0,.36-2V171.22h4Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
      <path d="M327.23,177.12c0-2.25-.05-4.1-.18-5.9h3.46l.18,3.51h.14a7.5,7.5,0,0,1,6.84-4,6.43,6.43,0,0,1,6.16,4.36h.09a9,9,0,0,1,2.43-2.83,7.46,7.46,0,0,1,4.82-1.53c2.88,0,7.15,1.89,7.15,9.45V193h-3.87V180.67c0-4.18-1.53-6.7-4.72-6.7a5.12,5.12,0,0,0-4.68,3.6,6.52,6.52,0,0,0-.32,2V193h-3.87V180c0-3.46-1.53-6-4.54-6a5.41,5.41,0,0,0-4.91,4,5.54,5.54,0,0,0-.31,1.93V193h-3.87Z" transform="translate(-119.42 -162.63)" />
    </svg>
  <div class="companion">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```